# Using `require` in JRuby in compiled and JIT modes

Tags: ruby, jvm, jruby

I have the following structure:

```
 lib/cf.jar
 lib/modules/basic_server.rb
 examples/server.rb
```

**lib/modules/basic_server.rb:**

```
require 'java'

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'cf.jar'))

module Cf
  import 'ch.ethz.inf.vs.californium.coap'
  import 'ch.ethz.inf.vs.californium.endpoint'
  import 'ch.ethz.inf.vs.californium.examples.resources'
  import 'ch.ethz.inf.vs.californium.util'
end
```

**examples/server.rb:**
    require(File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), '..', 'lib', 'modules', 'basic_server'))

```
class ExampleServer
  def initialize
    # Create the logger
    Cf::Log.init();
    # Create the endpoints container
    @ep = Cf::LocalEndpoint.new
    # Add a few basic endpoints
    @ep.addResource(Cf::HelloWorldResource.new)
    @ep.addResource(Cf::ZurichWeatherResource.new)
  end
end

srv = ExampleServer.new
```

And it all works when I run it with `jruby` command, however when I tried to compile it with `jrubyc` and then run with `java -cp .:$JRUBY_JAR examples/server` gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- file:/opt/devel/src/projects/californium-jruby.git/examples/../lib/modules/basic_server
```

So I see that using `File.dirname(__FILE__)` is probably wrong.

For a sanity check I tried to concatenate the code and it worked, though it doesn't seem to look like a solution for me. How do I `require()` in JRuby?

While writing this, I have figured that any use of relative path is not going to work and what have worked is this:

**lib/modules/basic_server.rb:**

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/cf.jar'
# ....
```

**examples/server.rb:**

```
require 'lib/modules/basic_server'
# ....
```

And compiling a JAR resulted in a working solution. However, now - how do I switch between the two behaviours?

I can run `jruby examples/server.rb` and I can't run `cd examples; jruby server.rb`, which is not too bad, though still, has anybody tackled this problem already?

By the way, a hack like this works:

```
if (File.dirname(__FILE__).split(':')[0] == 'jar') then
  require(File.join('lib', 'modules', 'basic_server'))
else
  require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', 'modules', 'basic_server'))
end
```

But it is rather quite ugly.

Comment: Did you try `require_relative`? Or even modify `$LOAD_PATH` somewhere in a startup file?

Comment: Ah, thanks - `jruby -I$PROJECT_ROOT` seems to solve the problem! Is there an environment variable that I can set, i.e. `JRUBY_FLAGS` or something like that? I don't really wanna do it in `~/.jrubyrc` ...